# RxJava: cancel event?

Tags: java, rx-java

Is it possible to cancel a single event in RxJava?

By that I mean something like this:

```
final protected PublishSubject<Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();
//...
subject.onNext(object);
//...
subject.cancel(object);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**:

No.

**Long answer**:

It is not possible to cancel the event, but it is possible to unsubscribe from `Observable` at the right time instead:

```
cancelEvents = BehaviourSubject.create();

// ...

subject
    .takeUntil(cancelEvents)
    .subscribe(...)

// ...

cancelEvents.onNext(someEvent);
```

Comment: Cool, that is what I was thinking.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, that is a new approach, I hadn't seen BehaviorSubject before